# Is it possible to compile (transpile) Scala to the browser, keeping the ability to interpret Scala code provided dynamically by the user?

Tags: javascript, scala, reflection, scala.js, transpiler

I know that Scala.js can transpile to JS, but it doesn't support reflection.
Is there any way to interpret user-provided Scala code without recurring to the server side?

If interpreting Scala in this way is not possible, is it possible to run a user-provided JavaScript code from the Scala code (i.e. from that Scala code that will be transpiled)?

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you really need to evaluate any arbitrary piece of code provided by the user?

Comment: At first just some primitives, like math ops and printing. Function  definitions as well, probably list manipulation...

Comment: Would it be feasible to create your own minimalistic language and write your own parser and interpreter?

Comment: Actually all of this is for a minimalistic language that embeds some form of "native" code to be able to do something. This is due to the extreme minimalistic approach: every functionality comes from the host language (as libraries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the first question: no, that is not possible. The Scala compiler cannot be compiled to JavaScript, for a number of reasons, which makes it impossible to compile user-provided code in the browser.

To the second question: yes, with `js.eval(dynamicJSCodeString)`. Standard warnings about `eval` and security apply.

Answer (score 3):

To the first question: yes, that is definitely possible. You just need to write a Scala interpreter either in ECMAScript or in a language for which a compiler to ECMAScript exists (e.g. TypeScript, CoffeeScript, Python, Ruby, Kotlin, or of course Scala), or in a language for which an interpreter exists that is written either in ECMAScript or in a language for which a compiler to ECMAScript exists … and of course you can chain those approaches as well.